# Argument labels do not match any availble overloads

Tags: swift

I'm trying to create an anagram tester, and I'm pretty sure the code I have should work, but I'm getting an error 'Argument labels '(_:)' do not match any available overloads' I've looked at the other posts regarding the same error, but I'm still not sure what this means or how to fix it.

```
var anagram1 : String!
var anagram2 : String!
var failure : Bool = false
var counter : Int = 0
print("Please enter first word: ")
anagram1 = readLine()
print("Please enter Second word: ")
anagram2 = readLine()

if anagram1.count == anagram2.count {
for i in anagram1.characters{
if (!failure){
    failure = true
    for y in anagram2.characters {
        counter += 1
        if i == y {

            failure = false
            anagram2.remove(at: String.Index(counter)) // error here

        }
    }
}
else {
    print("these words are not anagrams") 
    break;
    }
}
if (!failure) {
    print("these words ARE anagrams")

}
}
else{
    print ("these words aren't even the same length you fucking nonce")
}
```

Comment: try changing counter from Int to `counter = anagram2.startIndex` and instead of increasing it `counter =  anagram2.index(after: counter)` and in your error line `anagram2.remove(at: counter)` you should also change the anagram type to String initialising it to an emptyString and use `?? ""` after your readLine()

Comment: I tried what you said but now I get the issue of indexing past the end point of my string. is there no way of getting the method I'm using to work by just removing a character from a string at a given index(int)?

Comment: To prevent passing the endpoint you can do it in reverse order

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question: the error message **Argument labels '(_:)' do not match any available overloads** means that *you've given a function parameter names or types that don't match anything Swift knows about*.

The compiler is also trying to tell you what parameters to look at.  **'(_:)'** says that you're calling a function with an unlabeled parameter. (That means a value without any parameter name. A common example of a function that would look like this is `print("something")`. In Swift documentation, this would look like `print(_:)`.

Finally, **overloads** are ways to call a function with different information. Again using the `print` function as an example, you can call it multiple ways. A couple of the most common overloads would be:

```
// print something, followed by a newline character
print("something")

// print something, but stay on the same line
// (end with an empty string instead of the default newline character)
print("something", terminator: "")
```

Documented, these might look like `print(_:)` and `print(_:, terminator:)`.
*Note: these are broken down for explanation. The actual Swift documentation shows `func print(_: Any..., separator: String, terminator: String)` which covers a number of different overloads!*

Looking at the line where the error occurs, you see a function call and an initializer (which is essentially a function). Documented, the way you've entered the parameters, the functions would look like: `remove(at:)` and `String.Index(_:)`.

`String.Index(_:)` matches the parameters of the error message, so that's where your error is. There is no overload of the `String.Index` initializer that takes an unnamed parameter.

**To fix this error**, you need to find the correct way to create a String.Index parameter for the `remove(at:)` function. One way might be to try something like this:

```
for y in anagram2.characters.enumerated() {
    // `y` now represents a `tuple`: (offset: Int, element: Character)
    // so, you don't need `counter` anymore; use `offset` instead
    if i == y.element { //`i` is a Character, so it can compare to `element`
        ...
        let yIndex: String.Index = anagram2.index(anagram2.startIndex, offsetBy: y.offset)
        anagram2.remove(at: yIndex)
        ...
    }
}
```

---

**However**, there are other issues with your code that will cause further errors.

For one, you're looping through a string (`anagram2`) and trying to change it at the same time - not a good thing to do.

Good luck to you in solving the anagram problem!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help Leo but I found a way of doing it :)

```
if anagram1.count == anagram2.count {
for i in anagram1.characters{
if (!failure){
    counter = -1
    failure = true
    for y in anagram2.characters {
        counter += 1
        if i == y {

            failure = false
            if counter < anagram2.count {
            anagram2.remove(at: (anagram2.index(anagram2.startIndex, offsetBy: counter)))

                break;
            }



        }
    }
}
```