# Error "Argument labels '(min:, max:)' do not match any available overloads"

Tags: swift

This line is kicking back the error:

```
if Int.random(min: 1, max: 100) <= platformPercentage {
```

Full code:

```
func addRandomForegroundOverlay() {
    let overlaySprite: SKSpriteNode!
    let platformPercentage = 60
    if Int.random(min: 1, max: 100) <= platformPercentage {
        overlaySprite = platform5Across
    } else {
        overlaySprite = coinArrow
    }
    createForegroundOverlay(overlaySprite, flipX: false)
}
```

It is suppose to randomly place some platforms and some coins on the screen but the error won't even allow the game to run.

Comment: It just means that Swift doesnt know the function you are calling. More precisely the function exists but with other parameters, i.e. a different signature. See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46816385/5464805

Answer (score 4):

In a situation like this, simply look at the docs:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int/2995648-random

This method is not called `random(min:max:)`. It is called `random(in:)`. So go ye and do likewise:

```
if Int.random(in:1...100) <= platformPercentage {
```